# Expecting a Discontinuity in Piecewise Function on TI-89 but finding Unexpected Results

Tags: calculus, self-learning, calculator

When I look at the following function $f(x)$, it would seem to me that because there are no $\le$ or $\ge$ inequalities included where the function's formula changes (for the parts relating to `7`,) the integer `7` should *(most likely)* not be included in the line of this graphed function for $x$.

$$ f(x)=\begin {cases} \frac{5}{x-10}& x \le 5 \\\frac{5}{5x-30}& 5 \lt x \lt 7\\\frac{x-2}{12-x}& x \gt 7 \end {cases} $$

But when I go to graph the line *(and subsequently check the function's data table for values)* I find that the line of this function actually appears to continue through the integer `7` on my TI-89 calculator (and I am getting a defined value of `1.` for $y$ when $x$ equals `7`!)

Here is the nested `when()` functions I am using to graph this on the calculator:

```
when(x<7, when(x<=5, ((5)/(x-10)), ((5)/(5x-30))), ((x-2)/(12-x)))
```

How is it possible for $f(x)$ to be defined at the integer `7` if the integer `7` is being skipped in the rules for the function itself?

Comment: It is probably an artifact of how your calculator handles piecewise defined functions. The limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to $7$ is $1$, though, so (unless there's some context) there should not be any problem defining $f(7) =1$.

Comment: @Arthur Interesting point about the artifacts possibility.  As a follow-up to the last part of your comment: if I were to use $f(7)$, though, how would the function know what formula to use?  *(Which reminds me of case statements in programming languages... and how case statements often contain a "default" or "else" statement to catch extra cases...)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this ended up being an issue with the nested `when()` functions within the overall $f(x)$ function on a TI-89 calculator.  Nested `when()` statements are great for when there are no gaps between areas where the formula changes in a piecewise function.  But when there are gaps, nested `when()` functions can get pretty complicated.

Instead of using nested `when()` functions *(when there is a gap present in the line being graphed,)* [it is possible](http://education.ti.com/guidebooks/graphing/89ti/TI89TitaniumGuidebook_Part2_EN.pdf) to just define this piecewise function as an entire user-defined function (using the `Func` command on the calculator,) like this:

```
Func: If x<=5 Then:Return (5)/(x-10):ElseIf 5<x<7 Then:Return (5)/(5x-30):ElseIf x>7 Then:Return (x-2)/(12-x):Else:Return -1:EndIf:EndFunc
```

After using this newly-created function on the calculator, when checking the $f(7)$ in the table of the graphed function, `7` is now undefined* (as expected.)

**Note: "undefined" in this case is displayed as `-1` until I can find a better way to represent that the value does not exist at `7`.*

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the function is not defined at $x=7$.  The gap is just the one point, however, and the limit from both sides is $1$.  I am not surprised the graph looks like it goes through $(7,1)$ but it shouldn't be reporting a value at $7$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately, it may be the way I've entered the function into my calculator; when I use the `when()` command, it looks like it might be using the last part of the formula as a "catch-all" that includes the `7`...

Comment: Sorry for wasting everyone's time on this question; I'll try to find a better way to enter the function into my calculator to avoid the "catch-all" else statement that is happening;

Comment: Would this particular question be "too localized" for me to write down what I used to solve this issue?  (i.e. how to define a piecewise function that includes a gap between $x$ values on a TI-89)  If so, I can delete it;

Comment: @summea:  I think it would be, as it relates to the use of the specific calculator.  The mathematical point was that there was a gap in the domain of the function.  But I would leave what is here, and it probably doesn't hurt to put an answer to show what you found.